# Why am I getting invalid property value on background

Tags: php, css, wordpress

All I want to do is display an image. In my css I have

```
#logoImage{
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        left: 15px;
        height: 13px;
        padding: 7px 0 0 61px;
        background: <?php 
                if($logo_Image == null){echo "url(/img/Image.png)"; }
                else echo $logo_Image;
                ?>;
```

$logo_Image is already set with a get_field value. Also I have to place the ENTIRE url for the image to show up now. I don't know why that is.

EDIT:

I edited it to this:

```
#logoImage{
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        left: 15px;
        height: 13px;
        padding: 7px 0 0 61px;
        background: url(<?php if ($logo_Image == null){echo"/img/Image.png";}
        else echo $logo_Image; ?>);
```

And it now shows an image that I get from a wordpress plugin (ACF) however still no default image shows up.

EDIT: So all that needed to be done was to put the entire path in for the image...I Have no idea why it was unable to read the short path. Whatever. Thanks for your help and Ideas though

Comment: Is it in a `.css` file?

Comment: What the value of `$logo_image`? Is it something like `url(/img/blah.jpg)` or just `/img/blah.jpg`?

Comment: You can't use php inside .css files

Comment: @SimonM., I was gettin' to that! :D

Comment: I would assume this is a PHP file that generates CSS file

Comment: yes php file that generates css

Comment: try ```background: <?php echo ( $logo_Image ) ? $logo_Image : url(/img/Image.png); ?>``` assuming $logo_image is properly define

Comment: @silver that rendered an error... syntax error unexpected /

Comment: forgot the qoute lol

Comment: ```background: <?php echo ( $logo_Image ) ? $logo_Image : 'url(/img/Image.png)'; ?>```

Comment: @silver no error this time but the image is not being found...this is odd haha I know it is in the right path too

Comment: Try doing it in your html

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead in your **html**

```
<?php 
       $logo_to_set;
       if($logo_Image == null){$logo_to_set= "/img/Image.png"; }
          else echo $logo_to_set=$logo_Image;
            ?>
<img src="<?php echo $logo_to_set ?>">
```

Comment: It seems like the image is not showing up for some odd reason. It's in the right path however a 'broken, unloaded, standard image thing' is showing    EDIT: this thing http://www.millenniumforums.com/customavatars/avatar5840_6.gif